# WebAudio support on iOS "default" UIWebView/WebKit

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, web-audio-api, hybrid-mobile-app

Any suggestions for improving the question or it's title are welcome.

Objective questions up top, the full problem follows:

1. How would one determine which "version" of WebKit and/or which build/version of the WebAudio API is supported by a Cordova project? I am a complete novice to Objective-C and XCode, so forgive me if there's an obvious answer to this.
2. Is there a way to build Cordova apps using a more current version of WebKit to support more current WebAudio implementation?
3. A bit subjective, but can anyone comment on alternatives to WebAudio I could investigate, given my app's requirements, and how those alternatives work out in practice? I've unfortunately invested heavily in Javascript/HTML for this app, but need to consider if even diving into Objective-C to rewrite the app or build a native extension (plugin) is going to be fruitful.

Those requirements are basically:

- Play short audio samples (up to 2-3s) with latency below 50ms for response to UI.
- Latency needs to be fixed from the final callout. That is, from the final call to .playSound(...) there cannot be additional, variable latency. This is for a sequencer.
- Loads MP3 or OGG samples (not raw audio).
- Can dynamically load and unload sample sets.

The only options I'm aware of for iOS are Flash/AIR, Javascript w/ HTMl5 Audio, Javascript w/ WebAudio, and native Objective-C. The last includes native extensions/plugins as with Cordova.

**Lengthy description of the problem follows.**

I've hit a wall developing a guitar app for the iPad using Javascript, and am stuck with a few bad solutions. The app uses WebAudio to create a wavetable synth, and responds in real-time to user input. The *core* functionality of playback could get away with latency of ~100-200ms, but the feel of the app, and some secondary features rely on much more responsive ~10-50ms latency.

I (unwisely, yes) developed the app entirely in desktop Chrome and with some testing in iOS Safari, which encouraged me that everything would work. I (unwisely) held off on the unpleasant work of building using Cordova/Phonegap or alternatively CocoonJS, as I believed having fast iterative development outweighed test-driving on the (*cough*) target platform.

What's worse than finding out all your code doesn't work on your targeted platform? Discovering that it is very hard to determine if your code works on your targeted platform, because building and debugging are so problematic...

The problems I am running into, unexpectedly if deservedly:

- When building with Cordova, the app fails to initialize. I get no console output. The org.apache.cordova.console plugin works sporadically, and I cannot yet figure out if this is solvable (others have similar issues).
- I can open Safari and attach a remote dev console, but cannot do this *before* the app loads and initializes. So again, hard to figure out what may be happening with WebAudio.
- I have on some runs gotten a test WebAudio app to produce sound; on other runs it is silent. No console output to help identify this.
- Migration from webkitAudioContext to the final unprefixed AudioContext involves some minor code changes. However the former is (apparently) still used by the WebKit version that Cordova builds (or, the one that all native iOS apps have access to?), while the latter is used in the (far, far, far more useful and reliable for development) latest versions of Chrome. So, seems like I'll have to write some adapter code that can use either version of the API, but without reliable means to debug the one on my target platform.
- Lots of (not very recent) chatter on the interwebs makes me wonder if WebAudio is going to perform adequately in a hybrid app using its older version of WebKit (assuming I will eventually solve all of the above and get the app to make sound). I spent plenty of time profiling and optimizing to get it to run acceptably within Safari, not realizing this might be much different performance (or for that matter, *better* performance) than a stand-alone app.
- Not-specific to WebAudio, but my app takes *several* minutes to build on every change, due to the amount of (unchanging) audio samples that are copied multiple times by Cordova. This is one of many red flags telling me why Cordova/Phonegap have such a reputation as painful.

Bottom line at bottom, I'm stuck in a place where it may take considerable effort to determine if considerably more effort is warranted to pursue the tech choices already invested in (WebAudio, JS/HTML), and would love it if anyone with relevant experience could help me predict the outcome of that effort. I *could* start learning Objective-C and about writing native code for Cordova plugins (there are at least a couple existing projects to support simple native audio). I could likewise start going in the direction of a full rewrite in Flash, which would solve other problems in the app (like managing scalable UI and simplifying code and build management), but would as far as I understand guarantee a poor audio latency, and would certainly have other problems. I would love it if I could just get the existing codebase to work on iOS (iPad 2 & later). Unfortunately I don't have months to start over, but then if starting over is the only viable option...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well first I can give you some hints for debugging purposes:

I know from my own experience that such "loading errors" that appear before `deviceReady` is fired, are a real pain in the ass and pretty much hard to find.

Two things you could try:

First, to attach to the Safari remote debugger, write an `alert('test');` *before* initializing your WebAudio stuff. The trick there is, that the app execution is halted, as long as you didn't dispose the alert message. So there is enough time to attach the remote debugger, dispose the alert message and get the remote output from there on.

Another thing you could try for debugging is [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/), another remote debugger. For `weinre` to set up, install it via `sudo npm -g install weinre`, open a `weinre` localhost instance on your developer machine and paste the line `<script src="http://<your developer machine IP>:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>` into your `index.html`. If I remember it correctly, you have to inject this line before you include any other scripts.

Connect with your browser to `http://localhost:8080` to find the remote console there and start up your App. I found some hard-to-find issues in my code using this tool.

---

I can't help you specifically with WebAudio, but did you have a look at the [Low Latency Plugin for Phonegap](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/01/25/low-latency-polyphonic-audio-in-phonegap/)? I stumbled upon it some time ago when I had a few issues with audio latency on a Phonegap project and it proved quite helpful for me.

Have a look at the YouTube demonstration on the linked page. Through its ability to preload audio and some more improvements, it is quite performant and looks to fit your use case pretty good. And, of course, you would not need to write native code yourself.

Comment: The alert approach is a useful tip. I am partly wondering if the whole hybrid approach to mobile dev is still more trouble than its worth. What's frustrating is that my code, including low-latency audio, works great *on* the target device, in a web browser, and yet it is seeming possible that a) this may not be true for a Cordova (or similar) app, and b) trying to do the actual development on the target build is so onerous that it might be easier to start learning Objective-C. In that sense, anything that makes hybrid dev feel even *possible* would be very encouraging right now.

Comment: Well, I know your feeling, but unfortunately it is essential to always and continously test on the target device, a lesson I myself had to learn real quick when entering hybrid development. You should have a look at your build process, maybe there is still some optimizing potential. If you should try yourself at plugin development or debugging, I'd recommend to deploy using Xcode, as this proved for me to be faster and more comfortable for "native" debugging.

Answer (score 0):

1. While developing in the browser is handy, it is **no substitute** for a real device. This is true whether you use PhoneGap, Flash, Objective-C, etc.

   > Some of this you admit, but it's worth reiterating.

   - Never, *ever* assume that because your app works in your desktop that it will work on your target. While true for hybrid apps because of the varied WebKit versions available on iOS (dependent on OS version), it's also true for native apps. It's common knowledge that you should *never* rely on the iOS simulator to tell you *for sure* if the app will work correctly on a real device. Furthermore, the iOS simulator doesn't implement a lot of features that a real device will have, and so the only way to test is to use a real device.
   - Never, *ever* assume that if it runs well on your desktop that it will run well on your target. This is true of hybrid and non-hybrid development too. For example, the iOS Simulator is only constrained by the power of your PC, including speed and memory. That means an app can function perfectly on the simulator and crash on the real device due to memory constraints, or it may be fast on your desktop and excruciatingly slow on the device. Again, test on the real thing.
   - If possible, try to test on multiple devices. Optimize for the lowest speed device you're targeting. If you're going to target for iPhone 4s and later, get one and optimize for it -- optimizing for an iPhone 5s will help, but it only tells you about the iPhone 5s and nothing else.
   - Recognize that you aren't just targeting iOS, you're targeting specific WebKits. Each version of iOS has a different WebKit version, and it's non-negotiable. In other words, not only are you targeting iOS 6, 7, 7.1, but for hybrid development, you're targeting their WebKit version as well. Each has its own quirks and gotchas. (This is also true of native development as far as the platform SDKs go -- each version has its own quirks and gotchas.)
   - Cordova doesn't target a specific version of WebKit -- it targets the system web browser, or in iOS' case, `UIWebKit`. Whatever version the user has on their platform is the version you will get. Which makes Android horrible (in my opinion), but can cause some gnashing of teeth on iOS too. Test, test, test.
2. Research

   - Determining Web Audio support (and if any prefix is necessary) is easy: http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api (and click the "Show All" button if it isn't showing all iOS versions). Here you'll find out pretty easily that Web Audio is supported on iOS 6.0 and later using the `webkit` prefix. *Can I Use...* is a standard feature of my workflow when I'm contemplating using HTML5 or CSS3 features. There's a similar site for Ecmascript features (like http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/).
   - Consider using non-core plugins (though this will mean you can use the first bullet below). Search the Cordova plugin repository for audio -- there's a couple that look promising: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/search?search=audio. Also look at PlugReg: http://plugreg.com/search?q=audio. If you need to run both on the web and on the device, you'll want to detect the device you are on in order to know whether or not to use the plugins vs Web Audio. (Personally, it seems like it would be a good idea to abstract this out now so that you have a common interface to the audio generation backend, which would then be swappable based on the available technologies of the device.)

   > This said, I don't know if any of these plugins will serve your needs. Web Audio might be the best option here, but the only way to know if it works well on a device is *to try it*.
3. Fast Iterative Development

   - If you're willing to live with limited debugging options (that is, Weinre only), consider the PhoneGap Developer app (http://app.phonegap.com). As long as you don't use any non-core plugins, this allows you to have the app automatically reload whenever it detects changes in your code without a costly build cycle.
   - Although I don't typically suggest this, you could avoid some of the unnecessary copying by working in your platform `www` directory and deploying with Xcode. Just be sure to copy the changes back to the root `www` directory prior to using any CLI commands.
4. Debugging

   - Debugging with Safari is as good as it gets right now for iOS hybrid development. (Chrome dev tools are better, but them's for Android...) [Note: If using PhoneGap Developer App, this does not apply. You have to use Weinre instead, which is a far cry from Safari's debugger, unfortunately.]
   - Don't worry about logging to Xcode's console -- drop the console plugin requirement. Worry about logging to the browser's console instead. [Applies only when using Safari/Weinre as the debugger]
   - Consider GapDebug. They have a tool that doesn't continually close the debugger each time the app quits, which could be helpful.
   - The `alert` tip given by @qefzec is good. You can also use `window.location.reload()`. GapDebug can also help mitigate this, since it can often reconnect prior to anything important gets logged.
   - Be sure to enable breaking on all uncaught exceptions. (You can set this in the `Debugger` tab.) This helps catch errors you aren't even noticing. (Perhaps it's possible you're running into something like this with your intermittent Web Audio issues.)
   - Callbacks are hell to debug in any environment. Put a breakpoint at the top of the callback and then let the debugger continue executing (`|>` button). It'll skip over your callback code completely -- that's OK. It'll break into your callback when it is executed.
   - Even with all the debugging capabilities we have now (which don't yet match native), `console.log` and `alert` are still your friends.

Hopefully that helps some. Hybrid development can be rewarding, but it requires research and patience with not-quite-native debugging tools. The CLI is improving with each release, and some of what I'm seeing intended for 4.x will improve the CLI by leaps and bounds. You could go native, of course (and if you're doing a *lot* of audio processing, you may want to, or even just make a native plugin), but it comes with many of the same pitfalls as non-native development, so you aren't going to have a magically easier time of it. (My two cents.)

---

** Edit 9/7/2014 **

---

So I was partly blind while reading your original post and missed that you had, in fact, done some testing on iOS using Mobile Safari. **My bad!!** Here's a few caveats in that regard:

- Mobile Safari is *not* entirely the same thing as a UIWebView.
- Mobile Safari's *rendering* should be identical to a UIWebView rendering -- that is, the layout engines are the same.
- Mobile Safari uses a JIT compiler to improve JavaScript performance by something like 2-3x times. This engine is *not* provided to UIWebView instances, which means that any optimization you do in Mobile Safari is targeting the wrong engine.
- You can test layout and some "feel" (like size of elements and such) just fine in Mobile Safari.
- Don't rely on Mobile Safari to test performance. You really need to be an UIWebView. Of course, because all other browsers are UIWebView browsers, you can approximate this quite well by using Google Chrome or any of the other iOS browser alternatives (except Opera Mini), but you won't have debugging options.
- iOS 8 looks to change this, but only with WKWebView. There are plans on making PhoneGap work with this, but I would imagine them to be a little ways off (and only iOS 8 would see the performance improvements).
- There is one other key difference to be aware of -- when operating in a Cordova container, there's an additional iframe sitting in your DOM that acts as the web<->native bridge. It usually doesn't impact anything, but it's useful to know what it is doing there should you debug a Cordova app and see a DOM element you didn't physically have in your code.

Comment: I did not hear about GapDebug yet, but it looks quite promising, particularly that it leaves the debugger open when closing the app on the device (this is very annoying on Safari!). Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Kerri thanks for the detailed response. I'd like to respond to all of it. One comment though: I have been testing on the device all along, just within a browser as opposed to in a hybrid native app. So my suprise was that the WebKit used in **iOS** Safari on the target device appears to be a different WebKit than I get when I build the app using Cordova. Is this incorrect? If correct, I am trying to understand how to know which WebKit I am getting, and if incorrcet, trying to figure out what is different in the hybrid app vs. in Safari.

Comment: Also, I had used caniuse.com all along, which tells me my code should work on iOS 6.x+ (though now needing API sniffing as the unprefixed WebAudio requires). I had assumed all along that since I could find no more granular info about WebKit versions, that things should work once wrapped in a native container, albeit with some possible integration changes. Recently I determined that this assumption seems wrong, but I am still unclear. My app *has* run with *excellent performance* on the *target device*, using *WebKit*. In that sense, I did test from the outset on the target platform.

Comment: Oh hey I just realized who you are! It looks like your book is the one to read on the subject. I'm checking it out :)

Comment: Wow, I *totally* missed that you had referenced testing some on iOS Safari. D'oh!

Comment: So here's part of the problem there: The WebKit *rendering* is the same between iOS Mobile Safari and UIWebKit, but the JavaScript *engine* is not. Mobile Safari gets the benefit of Nitro, which is something like 2-3x faster than UIWebKit, and so testing for performance on Mobile Safari is not sufficient. (For some things like GPU rendering and stuff, it's OK, but not for computationally heavy JavaScript.) So you can use Mobile Safari to test look and feel to an extent, but also recognize that you're seeing an artificial performance boost from having JIT compiler involved.

Comment: Otherwise, what works on Mobile Safari should work in the container -- if you can get Web Audio working under Mobile Safari, it should always work within the container as well. If it doesn't, something is going very wrong.

Comment: Although I'd be happy to sell another copy of the book, you may already be beyond it - it covers a lot of PhoneGap, but it doesn't go into nearly as much detail with audio as you've already had to deal with -- it uses the media plugin to do audio capture and playback and that's the end of it. It does discuss localization, File API, DOM layout, other core plugins (GPS, Accelerometer, Network info, Video, etc.) and some third party plugins. So although I'd be happy for you to get it, I'm not sure it would help you in this situation. Now I've gone insane! Let me rectify that: buy my book, please!